# Understanding on not trigger the captch or any blockage of web scraping

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Trying to understand how certain rules of website are blocking bots/users.

Im using puppeteer to crawl certain informational website. Ive been using proxy every time I open and crawl the site. I also use user agent randomly for each visit. I also set random time to crawl the site interval-ly.

So Im trying to understand some things:

How do website block / ask for captcha ? How do they identify am I a bot or not? I was under the impression that with those tools that Ive set up, I should be considered unidentifable?

Any idea/info would be great

Comment: Maybe these can help: https://github.com/paulirish/headless-cat-n-mouse , https://javascriptwebscrapingguy.com/avoid-being-blocked-with-puppeteer/

Comment: There is an awful lot of things for websites to be suspicious of. Proxies you're using may have been "burned" and now have bad reputation. You could have visited too may pages in 1 session or crawl too quickly or else display behaviour somewhat unusual for a typical visitor.

Comment: Also are you using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)? Without this plugin detecting puppeteer is a breeze.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt yeah i have that running ...webdriver and all.. all are passed...trying my best to understand how website detect my presence and identify me via my ip where its always changing tho...

Comment: @Vaviloff yeah lets just say all those suspicions...how do the mark that its me...my ip always changing ....

Comment: @Vaviloff yeah im using it...its less frequent of getting the default captcha page with that being used but still being served captcha pages tho =|